# Enterprise library date formats

Tags: c#

I have two logs been created by enterprise logging (a log file for debug and an exceptions logs).

The date times of the logs written seem to be an hour or so off from the local time of the machine.

Any idea how to prevent this from happening?

JD.

Comment: Did you check that timezone settings are all correct between the machines?

Answer (score 2):

I would write the logs in UTC and only convert to local time on the view. The reasons for doing this include the log times will monotonically increase, if in local time when the clocks go back you have a log entry at an earlier time than an earlier log entry. UTC also makes it easier to compare logs on machines in different time zones.

Comment: @Mark : "only convert to local time on view". Can you give me more information on how this is done?

Comment: depends on the language but most will have a function that takes the UTC zone and the timezone resulting in the local time

Answer (score 0):

Either: your timezone is incorrect (either on a different machine that wrote them), or they are being written in UTC and you're viewing them as if they were written in your local daylight-time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies.

After researching a bit, I found that I can use a token like so {timestamp(local:F)} and this formats the date time and ensures it is the local date time, otherwise UTC is used.